# How to avoid jquery plugin required jquery itself

Tags: requirejs, r.js

I compiled js file for each html files, for example, index.html will have index.js, a.html will have a.js, and used `requirejs` to load it like:

#### index.html

```
<script scr="assets/js/build/index" src="assets/js/require.min.js"></script>
```

#### a.html

```
<script scr="assets/js/build/a" src="assets/js/require.min.js"></script>
```

Bebause of jquery is common and must include library, so I did not compiled it together, just put it in the body.

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script scr="assets/js/build/a" src="assets/js/require.min.js"></script>
```

But many plugin write dependency with jquery for nodejs I think, like [jquery file upload](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-file-upload/9.5.7/jquery.fileupload.js) or [blockUI](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.blockUI/2.66.0-2013.10.09/jquery.blockUI.js), they code something like:

```
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd && define.amd.jQuery) {
    define(['jquery'], setup);
} else {
    setup(jQuery);
}
```

When I use `r.js` to compile the js file, it will ask for jquery path and need to compile jquery together, is there any config to turn it off, I don't really want to remove it from the plugin by myself.

Comment: normally you should compile all files into one.. and have all the dependencies there..

Comment: I know, but jquery is the most fat js file to compile, when I use r.js compiled the file means jquery will not has cache, if I put jquery.js or bootstrap.js outside, browser can reuse it, and the complied file will be smaller

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to have RequireJS modules depend on code loaded with <script>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27845705/is-there-a-way-to-have-requirejs-modules-depend-on-code-loaded-with-script)

Comment: Totally different stuff...